# Xcode says Facebook app id isn't included in info.plist even though I have mentioned it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, info.plist

**[image]**

As you can see, I have included the Facebook app ID in my info.plist file. Everything works fine, until I click the 'login with Facebook' button. After that it stops and throws this error. I am also using the 'login with google' feature via firebase and have heard that this is the reason why it doesn't work. I really need to have both login options, please suggest what I should do to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName, LSApplicationQueriesSchemes are not in **item 0** of **URL types** .
They are located at the root dictionary :

[image]

Try deleting your configs, and paste the following code into the root of plist , not in URL types

```html
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbFBID</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>FBID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APPName</string>
```

Comment: Oh thanks, and where do I put the fb*********** app id?

Comment: In URL types, reference here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: I followed both, your instructions and the Facebook documentation word-by-word, and yet the problem seems to persist. Is there any other solution? Sorry for asking for too much

Comment: Did you add the "fb" prefix for FacebookAppID?

Comment: thanks, and should I add the 'LSApplicationQueriesSchemes' in the root as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Is the issue on Facebook's end? or is it my code that is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231126/discussion-between-kevin-thomas-and-nguyen-hoan).